# How to edit my query to have a more accurate user retention result?

Tags: mysql

My goal is to find how many of the visitors that entered my website during the last 7 days, have also visited today.
That means if someone visited `05-02` and today, it will count it on `05-02`.

The problem with my query is that if someone visited `05-01` and `05-02` and also today, it will count him only on `05-01`. But I want the query to count him on `05-02` also.

How can I edit the query below to do this?

```
SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT v.`hash` ) hashCount, DATE( v.`timestamp` ) AS views
FROM audience v
INNER JOIN behaviour b ON v.`hash` = b.`hash` 
WHERE v.timestamp
BETWEEN SUBDATE( CURDATE( ) , 7 ) 
AND CURDATE( ) 
AND DATE( b.timestamp ) = CURDATE( ) 
GROUP BY views
```

Comment: It would be helpful to set something up at http://mysqlfiddle.com with some sample data.

Comment: It's hard to fix your query without knowing what the tables contain, so add the table descriptions, some sample data (just use 1,2,3, ... for 'hash' and some timestamps for both tables), and the expected result for this. If I had to guess: `audience`=list of first visits, `behaviour`=page visits of these users? Then your `group by views` will take the date of the registration/first visit (and thus not differ between visit dates) - you probably just need to add `b.timestamp` to your `distinct` then. But please just add the missing information, so we don't have to guess.

Comment: Hi, are you satisfied with my answer? I would be glad to receive feedback from you.

Answer (score 2):

> To make it easier just take all people who visited totay and look for
>   a visit in the past 7 days and if one is found return the last date of
>   visit. i think this approach is easier to comprehend:

```
select b.`hash` ,  
       audience.last_visit 
from behaviour b
 inner join (select v.`hash`, max(v.timestamp) as last_visit from audience v
  where DATE(v.timestamp) between date_sub(current_date, interval 7 day) and 
  date_sub(current_date, interval 1 day)  
  group by v.`hash`) as audience 
 on(b.`hash` = audience.`hash`)
where DATE(b.timestamp) = CURDATE();
```

> - We join on a select that already consists of the information we need (latest visit per hash during the last 7 days).
>
> > The number of rows returned is the number of visitors who visited your
> >     page today and during the last week.

**You can also count from your select to get the number you were looking for as a query result:**

```
select count(*) from    
(select b.`hash` ,  
       audience.last_visit 
from behaviour b
 inner join (select v.`hash`, max(v.timestamp) as last_visit from audience v
  where DATE(v.timestamp) between date_sub(current_date, interval 7 day) and 
  date_sub(current_date, interval 1 day)  
  group by v.`hash`) as audience 
 on(b.`hash` = audience.`hash`)
where DATE(b.timestamp) = CURDATE() ) as my_visitors;
```

**- Testdata**

```
    drop table if exists your_schema.behaviour;
    create table your_schema.behaviour(`hash` varchar(255), `timestamp` timestamp) ;

    insert into your_schema.behaviour
    values ('ab','2016-05-23'),('ac','2016-05-23');

    drop table if exists your_schema.audience;
    create table your_schema.audience (`hash` varchar(255), `timestamp` timestamp) ;
insert into your_schema.audience
values ('ab','2016-05-01'),('ab','2016-05-02'),('ab','2016-05-03'),('ab','2016-05-04'),('ab','2016-05-21'),('ab','2016-05-23'),
       ('ac','2016-05-01'),('ac','2016-05-02'),('ac','2016-05-03'),('ac','2016-05-04'),('ac','2016-05-21'),('ac','2016-05-23'),
       ('ad','2016-05-01'), ('ad','2016-05-02'), ('ad','2016-05-03'),('ad','2016-05-04'),('ad','2016-05-21'),('ad','2016-05-23');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do by using **DATE_SUB**, check following query

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT v.`hash`) AS hashCount, DATE(v.`timestamp`) AS views
FROM audience v
INNER JOIN behaviour b ON v.`hash` = b.`hash` 
WHERE views >= DATE_SUB(Now(),INTERVAL 7 DAY)
GROUP BY views
```

for more information visit following url

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the `DATE - INTERVAL ? DAY` function. Examine the sample below:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT v.`hash`) AS hashCount, DATE(v.`timestamp`) AS views
FROM audience v
INNER JOIN behaviour b ON v.`hash` = b.`hash` 
WHERE views >= DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 7 DAY
GROUP BY views
```

> Go here for more [Date and Time Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html).